# C++ expression is not assignable when writing `&str_send[0] = &str_recv[c * 6];`

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to parse an array that receives a multiple of 8 bytes and sends back each array of 8 bytes one at a time.

I'm getting an `expression is not assignable` or `lvalue required as left operand of assignment` error when building

I'm trying to figure out why I cannot simply change the address of an array to the new position. At first I thought it was a C-style array issue, but the same error happened when I tried with `std::vector<unsigned char>`

Is there a preferable way of doing this without copying the bytes?

Thanks,

```
unsigned char str_send[8];
unsigned char str_recv[BUF_SIZE];

int n = receive(cport_nr, str_recv, (int)BUF_SIZE);

if (n > 0 && ( n % 8 == 0 ) )
{
    for (int c = 0; c < n / 8; c++) //Break up multiple 8-byte chunks
    {       
        &str_send[0] = &str_recv[c * 6]; //ERROR expression is not assignable
    }
}
return (0);
```

Comment: Variables have a fixed location in memory for their entire life, you can't move one or change its address.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. You can't change the address of a variable. If you have a pointer (you don't) you can change what it points to.

Comment: Why are you doing `c * 6`? And what do you want to have at the end? Even if you could assign the address you would end up with only a single address in str_send.

Comment: Question is very unclear. What does "sends back" mean? Pointing a pointer at an object does not send it anywhere. Copying it, perhaps, does so. What does "one at a time" mean? Are you wanting to do something with individual bytes, or with individual groups of 8 bytes? Where does the magic number 6 come from? You've used it twice, without explanation.

Comment: All of your questions literally have nothing to do with the topic of the question. So your downvotes are entirely opinion based.

Comment: `n` is the number of bytes received, `c` is the number of 8-byte packets in the data received, and `str_send` replies data back 8 bytes at a time for the simplicity of this question. I wanted the str_send to point to the location in memory where 8 bytes of the received data are stored. But it would be impossible without inserting a NULL character, which would corrupt the data

Comment: It is trivially easy to get "`str_send` to point to the location in memory where 8 bytes of the received data are stored... without inserting a NULL character, which would corrupt the data". The fact that _people could not tell_ that that's what you wanted to do, from reading your question, is a better explanation of why it was down-voted than "entirely opinion based".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the address of a variable.

What you *could* do is create an array of pointers to the original array, but then you're just copying addresses (probably 8 bytes each) instead of single byte values.  Then you've have to dereference those pointers, which makes it non-trivial to send what they point to.

Copying the bytes is exactly what you want to do here.  Then you have a buffer you can send as-is:

```
str_send[0] = str_recv[c * 6];
```

Comment: Your suggested code copies 1 byte;  I suspect OP wanted to copy 6 bytes although it is not completely clear.

Comment: This way I'm just copying 1 byte, I think that creating the pointer comment above was the right answer